# How to change multiple choice text value into number in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have simple Google Form in which there are a set of questions, whose answers are either `Yes` or `No`. I want to assign predefined mark/rating based on the question (Scale: 1 to 5) answered by the user. Now all this input is stored in Google Spreadsheet.

On Form: the question are:

1. Fixed Score value 4, if User answered/selected Yes
2. Fixed Score value 3 if answered as Yes
3. Fixed Score 1 if answered as Yes

If User selected No, it has default fixed value 0

Now how do i get these numerical values available in spreadsheet response instead of Yes or No values?

Comment: did you use a google form or did you design it yourself with UI service ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas I have no knowledge about UI Service, i simply used Google Form.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options for doing this:
1. You can build your own form using google apps scrip see UiApp.
2. Make a normal form with the questions and use functions in ur spreadsheet like: =IF(a1,yes,4) etc

Id suggest a custom form.

Comment: Thank you.. `=IF(a1,yes,4)` is helpful. but does it triggers when form is submitted?

Comment: You should have a look [at this doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=fr-FR)  , the values in the form are available as e.values which is an array containing all your answers... then a couple of 'if' will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

i think this could help you, if you are thinking in write your google script with trigger!

```
function doGet() {

var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("formulario");
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("panel");
var labelAsk = app.createLabel().setId("ask").setText("MY QUESTION IS HERE");
var value = app.createListBox().setId("value");
value.setItemText(0, "Choose");
value.setItemText(1, "1");
value.setItemText(2, "2");
value.setItemText(3, "3");
value.setItemText(4, "4");

var button = app.createButton().addClickHandler(handler).setId("button").setText("send");
var handler = app.createServerHandler("check").addCallbackElement("panel");
button.addClickHandler(handler);

 panel.add(labelAsk);
 panel.add(button);
 app.add(panel);

return app;

};
function check(e){
 try{
var value = e.parameter.value;
 switch(value){
   case "1": change option in cell of spreadsheet;
   case "2": change option in cell of spreadsheet;
   case "3": change option in cell of spreadsheet;
   case "4": change option in cell of spreadsheet;
   default:  change option in cell of spreadsheet;
  }//end if
 }//end try
  catch(e){ error_en_e_parameter_value}
 return app;
};
```